# How to express the supertype of a generic

Tags: c#, generics

Given a generic type `IHandler<T>` how do I express the supertype for this so that I can for example declare a `List<T2>` where T2 is any `IHandler<T>`?

This question is not about lists. The list code is a contrived concrete example included to meet your requirement for sample code.

This question is about open generics, to which the concept of variance also applies. I didn't so much as mention lists in the title.

```cs
public class NotGeneric
{
  private readonly List<dunno> _handlers = new();
  public AddHandler(IHandler<dunno> handler)
  {
    _handlers.Add(handler);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have a variance problem. Which you can solve by introducing a new type `IHander<T> : IHandler`, so that you can create a `List<IHandler>`

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `IHandler<T>`? Is `IHandler<T>` a part of your own code or you don't have control over it?

Comment: Funny you should say that, @JeremyLakeman. That's exactly what I've done.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman your comment is the method I eventually went with. Put it up as the answer. And I think you should emphasize the "variance" observation. Being able to articulate the problem sets one on the path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Covariant and Contravariant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/) types add an extra dimension to the .net Type system. Allowing some variable assignments, but disallowing others.

Since you want to use a single `List<T>` to store references to multiple generic types. You have a variance problem.

I've found that you can solve most variance problems either by introducing a new type with fewer generic constraints. In your case I would introduce a non-generic interface, which you may find useful in other ways;

```cs
public interface IHandler{}
public interface IHandler<T> : IHandler{}
private readonly List<IHandler> _handlers;
```

Or by adding more generic constraints. Usually by forcing the definition of each type parameter into the caller. Though this isn't really applicable to your problem.